# How to remove text from previous element if condition is not satisfied - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm making small app in react js which basically would display SELECTED if item is selected.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


function SelectedFiles(props) {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(0);

  const selectSelectedFileOnChange = id => {
    setSelectedFile(id);
    props.onSetSelectedFile(id);
  };

  return (
    <MainContainer>
      <RadioButton
        key={props.id}
        value={props.id}
        name="Acfile"
        onChange={e => {
          selectSelectedFileOnChange(props.id);
        }}
        disabled={false}
      ></RadioButton>
      <span>{props.file.name}</span>
      <span>{props.file.size}</span>
      <span>{props.file.isPrimary === true ? 'SELECTED' : null}</span>

    </MainContainer>
  );
}

export default SelectedFiles;
```

This component is part of parent component and purpose of this component is just to display an items:

```
<AddF className="modal-body">
  {docs && docs.length > 0
    ? docs.map(file => (
        <SelectedFiles
          key={file.id}
          id={file.id}
          file={file}
          onSetSelectedFile={handleSetPrimaryFile}
        />
      ))
    : null}
</AddF>

  const handleSetPrimaryFile = id => {
    props.onSetPrimaryFile(id);
  };
```

As its possible to see guys I dont know how to remove text from NOT SELECTED element..

Thanks guys ! Cheers

Comment: @keikai updated an question, was typo while pasting

Comment: @keikai I've added it, its doing nothing but passing an id to component

Comment: Still can't tell since how `onSetPrimaryFile` operate your data remains in dark, you may try to console the `props` inside `<SelectedFiles />` to find what has changed after you make a checkbox change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try below and see if it works?

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState({docs[0].id: true});
<AddF className="modal-body">
  {docs && docs.length > 0
    ? docs.map(file => (
        <SelectedFiles
          key={file.id}
          id={file.id}
          file={file}
          isPrimary={!!files[file.id]}
          onSetSelectedFile={handleSetPrimaryFile}
        />
      ))
    : null}
</AddF>

  const handleSetPrimaryFile = id => {
    setFiles({[id]: true});
    props.onSetPrimaryFile(id);
  };
```

Change `SelectedFiles.js` as

```
  <span>{props.isPrimary === true ? 'SELECTED' : null}</span>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet `{props.file.isPrimary === true ? 'SELECTED' : null}` is determining when `SELECTED` should appear. But I don't see where `props.file` would ever change.

I also see you using both the `useState` hook and some sort of prop function passed in to handle selection.

The solution is to have some sort of unique identifier for the files (perhaps that's `file.id`), then check this value on the `selectedFile` to determine if `SELECTED` should appear, e.g., `props.file.id === selectedFile`.